# Best way to pass varying data into directive from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have a button that will execute a query and put the results into a directive that is dynamically generated, each query result is mapped to one directive (Think notebook style processing). What is a good way to pass data into directives this way? I tried using binding through scope but it seems to update all my directives with the same data. I could use a map to map my data into each directive, but I think there is probably a better way. Here is what I have

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('DOController', ["$scope", "$compile",
    function($scope, $compile) {

        var i = 0;


        $scope.execute = function() {
            console.log("Executing");
            $scope.data = "testData" + i++;
            // Dynamically Add notebook pages
            var notebookPage = $compile("<notebook-page data='data'></notebook-page>")($scope);
            var notebookContainer = document.getElementById('notebook-container');
            angular.element(notebookContainer).prepend(notebookPage);

        }

    }

 ])
.directive('notebookPage', function() {

    var controller = function(){

    }

    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'notebookpage.html',
        scope: {
            data: '=data'
          }
    }
});
```

html

```
<div class="notebook-page">
     <p>{{data}}</p>

</div>
```

Edit: I think I found the solution

```
  var notebookPage = $compile("<notebook-page data=" + someDataHere + "></notebook-page>")($scope);
```